# Crossing US border just to take another flight and times/rules to be considered

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, tickets, lax, bkk

I am planning a trip to Bangkok, Thailand (BKK) departing from Lima, Peru (LIM) and I'm a Peruvian citizen.

I am making my own itinerary since I found cheaper prices when booking flights separately.

Here's what I am planning to book:

[image]

[image]

But the following questions came up:

**1. Is there a problem to cross the US border through LAX just to take another flight? (Holding a B1/B2 visa and 2 times, one on my way to BKK and another when going back to LIM)**

I mean, I know immigration normally stamps your passport with the maximum time that you are allowed to stay but, since I will enter the country and then leave in some hours, I don't know if this will be a problem or not (when re-entering the country) or if I'm ignoring something like a rule that maybe I should know.

**2. If there's no problem with the 1st question then I'd like to know if the times between each flight that I am planning to book are fair enough.**

So, I know the times to go through immigration/taking your bags/customs vary from airport to airport but maybe someone knows better about LAX. Apart from that, on each flight I am considering the 3h needed before each international departure and some extra time in case of a possible delay. However, I am especially doubting if the time before taking the flight from LAX to LIM is enough.

Comment: I do #1 quite regularly (without a visa, just VWP). The worst that happened is once I received a one day entry stamp instead of 90 days.

Comment: Technically, transit is category C while category B is for temporary visits.  But it's well established that a category B visa may also be used for transit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is there a problem to cross the US border through LAX (holding a B1/B2 visa and 2 times, one on my way to BKK and another when going
>      back to LIM) just to take another flight?

All things being equal you should be fine

> 2. If there's no problem with the first question then I would like to know if the times between each flight that I am planning to book are
>      enough.

More than enough time, even factoring in a couple hours of delay and crossing security and changing terminals. You have minimum 6+ hours. The [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Switch-Flights-in-LAX) provides a walk-through changing terminals in LAX.

Comment: @OscarJara We answered a similar question here just a couple of days ago. I hope you understand that if for some crazy reason you're not allowed into the USA on your first leg from Lima, it's going to cost you a lot of money to cancel and rebook your tickets.

Comment: Well, it's not my first time traveling to the US and yeah, I hope that crazy scenario doesn't happen.

Comment: @OscarJara Great then, because you save about $700 or more doing it this way.

Comment: @Oscar How did it go? I believe it went smoothly. Been two years.

Comment: All went fine, I really enjoyed the trip and no one asked a thing about my plans when crossing the US border.